# Comment markdown seen unescaped by symbolhound?

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown, search-engine

If I do a symbolhound search for `Could you give an example of what you _`, I get a match with

```
Regular expressions in Ruby
included. Where is the mistake or what do I have to change to get the correct array? Tags: ruby regex
Could you give an example of what you _want_ the matched
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900319/regular-expressions-in-ruby
```

`_want_` shouldn't have underscores appearing to symbolhound. It makes it harder to search for underscores in Stack Overflow.

Comment: What is symbolhound? Where does it come from? How does it work? Why should we cater to it? How popular is it—do lots of people use it?

Comment: @TheEstablishment Thanks for your feedback. I didn't anticipate needing to provide that kind of information.

Comment: Isn't that a problem with symbolhound rather than SO?

Comment: Apparently [symbolhound](http://www.symbolhound.com/) is a code search engine. I learned something today! *...dogs don't lay eggs.*

Comment: Shouldn't this be closed as "too localized", not as "off topic"?

Comment: I'm not sure why it should be closed at all...

Comment: It appears it [was broken in April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

...how is this our bug?  This isn't something we could possibly fix, you would need to ask symbolhound why they behave this way.

To be clear: we render to them the same way we do to you, *they're* doing the underscores.